# Is that true for given group if their divisors are isomorphic, then their quotient group are isomorphic?

Tags: group-theory

I think there will be counter examples in both cases:

For given group $G$ and its normal group $H,K$

(1) If $H$ and $K$ are isomorphic then $G/H$ are $G/K$ are isomorphic

(2) If $G/H$ are $G/K$ are isomorphic then $H$ and $K$ are isomorphic.

I tried proof by using first isomorphism theorem, but failed.

Also I think It is hard to find counter example using simple trial as Direct groups. Are they true or false?

Comment: They are both false, and there are counterexamples with $|G|=8$ for both statements, so you should be able to find them!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$1)$ Let $G=S_3\times Z_3$ and $H=A_3\times 1$ and $K=1\times Z_3$

$G/H=Z_2\times Z_3$ but $G/K=S_3\times 1$

$2)$ $G=S_3\times Z_2$ and $H=A_3\times Z_2$ and $K=S_3\times 1$ then $G/H\cong G/K\cong Z_2$ but $H,K$ are non isomorphic.

Answer (score 0):

1) Take  $G$ be the group **Z**. Then for two different positive integers, $m,n$, the subgroups generated by $m$ and $n$ are isomorphic, but not the quotients by them.

2) Take an abelian group of order $p^3$, p a prime, that is a direct  product
 of two cyclic groups, $C_{p^2}\times C_p$. If we quotient by the first factor we get a cyclic group of order $p$, if quotient by $C_p\times C_p$ again we get a cyclic group of order $p$.